# Decode hexadecimal string in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, encode

So, I'm trying to scrape a website which, as part of its payload in requests, has a token as follows

```
"9976c535-c53a-4c91-926c-8dada3f8086e"
"99426794-ea7b-4773-b0a7-715fc7ee224f"
"6492978c-54a1-44c0-b98f-9fd07f5e872f"
```

At first I thought it could be a date like string encoded, such as 2020-04-10-18-542312 but this 3 strings from above are seconds apart, so 2020 should be encoded the same.
Does anyone know if from a date you can generate a hexadecimal that encodes using the whole sequence instead of number by number?

Next, I tried to decode the strings as follows

```
bytes.fromhex('9976c535').decode('ascii')
>>UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x99 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The mistake is the same if I try other sequences like 4c91 or a different encoding such as utf-8.

Why this is happening? How can I get the original string from the above codes?

EDIT: As the comments suggest, those strings are just tokens with no actual meaning behind them. If you do `secrets.token_hex(4)` for the first part, `secrets.token_hex(2)` for the next 3 and `secrets.token_hex(6)` for the last part, this token serves its purpose just as fine, so there is no actual point in trying to decode them.

I don't know what is the use for this in website APIs though

Comment: These codes could mean *anything*. We don't even know if there *is* an original string.

Comment: That's a version 4 UUID - it's random. It's not an encoding of anything.

Comment: Seems you are correct and its just a random token. I tried secrets.token_hex(2) to generate a random string and the page actually returned correct values. I don't know what's the use of this. Thanks!